# How do I install the Visual Web Developer feature for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-web-developer

I have Visual Studio 2010 Premium installed, and I want to install the Silverlight 4 SDK.

The SDK says that it requires the Visual Web Developer feature for Visual Studio 2010.  Any idea as to how to install, or activate this feature?

---

[image]

Comment: I saw a similar message during a 'web platform installer' http://i.imgur.com/F4MEGBC.png

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Run the Visual Studio installer and double check the installed components. Make sure Web Developer is enabled (Web Developer should be part of the standard installation for VS 2010 Premium) and then hit OK.

Once the installation has completed try installing the Silverlight SDK again.

Comment: Yip... that's the answer.  It was actually installed.  I had to uninstall and re-install it for the SDK to recognize it.  Now the SDK's hanging two thirds of the way through installation... fun times :)

Comment: no... wait... it's gotten to 90%!  This is getting exciting... okay - I'll stop talking rubbish now.

Comment: the amount of work it was to find this answer is pathetic.  I realize that MS has a lot to document, but the error message could have easily told me in one sentence what I had to go through way too much work to find.

Comment: I know this is old but the same answer applies to Visual Studio 2012

Answer (score 6):

1. Rerun visual studio setup
2. Select modify
3. Choose option "Microsoft web Developer Tools"

[image]

Answer (score 5):

With Windows Azure, this is not as straightforward, because there is no separate VS installer. After launching VS2010SP1AzurePack.2E2.2E1.exe, you will eventually get this message. Once you do, click OK. Then on the next screen, where it has all the software products listed and the "I Accept" button is grayed out, scroll down to the "Visual Web Developer 2010 Express (Dependency)" line, and click on the "Direct Download" link underneath it. Run the "vwd_web.exe" file that it downloaded, and it will install Visual Web Developer 2010 Express. Once that completes, click on the "I Decline" button back on the list of products. That returns you to the first screen. Now click the "Install" button - the message will not appear, and the "I Accept" button on the next screen will now be enabled.

Comment: Alternatively, you can download dependencies for visual studio here: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/archive-net-downloads/

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I had already chosen the Web Dev feature, and performed the following

1. New Project
2. Cloud Project
3. Get Azure SDK
4. Click the Download Azure button
5. WebPI kicked off
6. Closed VS
7. Clicked Accept

Azure SDK (2.9.1) installed.